# pulling mentions from twitter with php

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to retrieve mentions from twitter using php.  The current code I have works fine to retrieve the user_timeline, however when I try to use the same code for the mentions I get an authentication error.  What is the best way to retrieve mentions with userid, pictures, text, etc included?

if I change user_time to mentions I get an authentication error.

Here is the code I use now to retrieve user_timeline with php.

```
<?php

$xmldata = "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_time/usernid.xml";

$open = fopen($xmldata,'r');

$content = stream_get_contents($open);

fclose($open);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content); 

$screenname = $xml->status[0]->user->screen_name;





?>
```

Comment: Im going to bank that this is level of access requires you to have an app registered with twitter dev, and use oauth to access the service api's.. twitter does have some publicly available things such as the time_lines, but a lot of other stuff requires you to have an app registered.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use OAUTH ("Returns the 20 most recent mentions (status containing @username) for the **authenticating** user."):

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/mentions

Try: https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth or http://www.joeyrivera.com/2010/twitter-api-oauth-authentication-and-zend_oauth-tutorial/ and https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new